# AsyncTask.onPostExecute() displaying AlertDialog when app is minimized causes unresponing UI

Tags: android, user-interface, android-asynctask

Strange effect in displaying an AlertDialog inside AsyncTask: if the application **is minimized during the execution of the AsyncTask**:

```
private class CheckDeviceConfiguration extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();    
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ActivitySIPCountrySelection.this, "Title", "working...", true);                        
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    progressDialog.dismiss(); //hide progress dialog previously shown

    if (!result) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivitySIPCountrySelection.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Message");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            //do something
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
     }

  }
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params)
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return false;
}
```

}

If I click on my app icon to restore, the UI is not responding and the activity looks a bit **darkened** (inactive?). Back button has no effect.

**Edit:**

Someone asks where I call AsyncTask. Well, from the Activity onCreate().

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sip_country_selection);

        new CheckDeviceConfiguration().execute();
    }
```

The async task shows correctly a progress dialog and hide it in onPostExecute.

Comment: fom where do you call asynctask?.((Activity)mContext).finish(); mContext is your activity context. Pass context to asynctask constructor and then use that context to call finish()

Comment: edited, thanks. added the onPreExcute() part.

Comment: @Raghunandan the finish() is not called, forget it.

Comment: your doInBackground() code? can you post the same.

Comment: does some Socket communication and Thread.Sleep()...

Comment: I tired the same on my samsung galaxy s3 works fine.  What do you mean by app minimized?

Comment: hit home button while task is executing: minimize task, wait 5 secs and return to app. UI freezed

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: AsyncTask manages a thread pool, created with ThreadPoolExecutor. It will have from 5 to 128 threads. If there are more than 5 threads, those extra threads will stick around for at most 10 seconds before being removed. (note: these figures are for the presently-visible open source code and vary by Android release).

Leave the AsyncTask threads alone, please.

Pressing the Home switches you from the app to the home screen, whilst leaving your app running in the background.

When your phone is running low on resources like memory it will start to close apps that are running in the background, so that your phone has enough resources for what you're trying to do now. Games are often amongst the first apps the phone will "kill" to save resources as they often use a lot more memory and CPU than other apps. This is why sometimes your game is still running paused, and sometimes Android has closed it for you.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. For more details check tasks and back task.

You can cancel asynctask by calling cancel(true), an interrupt will be sent to the background thread, which may help interruptible tasks. Otherwise, you should simply make sure to check isCancelled() regularly in your doInBackground() method.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
d.cancel(true);
if(d.isCancelled())
{
    System.out.println("Destroyed....");
}
 }
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDestroy();
d.cancel(true);
if(d.isCancelled())
{
    System.out.println("Destroyed....");
}
}
```

SO when your activity resumes create a new instance of asynctask and execute again.

http://code.google.com/p/shelves/. Check shelves project by Romain Guy.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html. Also check asynctask loader.

An alternative to asynctask is RoboSpice.
https://github.com/octo-online/robospice.

FAQ's https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Advanced-RoboSpice-Usages-and-FAQ.

Comment: So your're sugesting to cancel the task if the Activity is paused? But... what can I do If I can't cancel the task?

Comment: you can cancel asyntask by calling canel(true)

Comment: Sorry, I explain it better: At this point, I can't cancel the the AsyncTask without managing that. Maybe I've to rethink to my approach and manage the "cancel" situation.

Comment: what do you mean by managing that??. Also you need to consider a situation when device orientation changes. Activity will be destroyed and recreated.

Comment: to understand better check the shveles project by Romain GUy.

Comment: Yes, my application display activity only on "portrait mode" so I've no problem with device orientation... I'll check the link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26813/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-seraphim)